# nGinx non-www to www redirect

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, nginx

I have been working with apache for years and now wanted to move to nGinx keeping in view the performance everyone on internet seems to be talking about. But I its very frustrating for me for not being able to rewrite a non-www url to www i.e. example.com to www.example.com

I have referred to all the posts on StackOverflow and have tried their configurations. Somehow the system does not seem to work. I have wasted more than 2 hours in this and need help from you. **My nGinx version is 1.2.1**. This was 15sec work in Apache. I have somehow started missing apache.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from my site [www.yes-www.org](http://www.yes-www.org/redirection/):

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

Your other `server` block should not respond to `example.com`, but only `www.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

do not worry...I could find a solution:

```
 if ($host = 'ukrugbyshop.com' ) {
         rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://www.ukrugbyshop.com  permanent;
      }
```

Comment: That is actually an inefficient solution as every single request to your site will be tested whether needed or not. Best solution is to create a separate server block with `server_name ukrugbyshop.com` and within that block, put `return 301 http://www.ukrugbyshop.com$request_uri;` In this way, requests with the `www` will not have to waste time going through the `if` test. See: http://superuser.com/questions/351940